# Copy graphics to other graphics in Java

Tags: java, graphics

I have an instance of the class `Graphics` called `graphics`. I have another instance of `Graphics` called `g`. I wish to take everything painted on `graphics` and draw it onto `g`. I have no code, because I do not know where to start. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: does the class `Graphics` not have a copy constructor?

Comment: A Graphics object is used to draw ONTO something, not FROM something. So you can't do painting with just two Graphics objects. We need more context to help answer the question.

Comment: @masfo001 No, `Graphics` is abstract is normally generated by the system

Comment: If you can use the `Graphics` context of something like `BufferedImage`, you can use to render to, then draw the resulting image to the other `Graphics` context